# sum values which satisfy conditions in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, sum, match, google-query-language

I try to do a formulae which should check column A and if in cell value is 1 than formulae should take value in column B and sum with others which satisfy conditions

sheet example))
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hjP1-EgQYvKDOM6wYj_NmFiOXAsaAOAgaFGWf8feJxw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:A&""\ B2:B}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]